# Suggestions for how to define command line parameters

Tags: delphi, paramstr

In my Delphi application, I would like to add command line parameters to automatically set some parameters in the login screen.

Currently I have a login screen where the user sets some information (like Server, database, user, password, AuthenticationType, AUtoLogin, ...).

I use MRU to populate the fields. Anyway, in big organizations, there is the need to do not let the user choose any info. For this, the simplest thing I can do in my scenario is to use command line parameters.

My question is how do you suggest to choose the command line parameters? I mean, should I go for a "position" approach or for some "tag" approach, for example:

```
MyProject.exe -s:MYSERVER -d:DATABASE
```

or

```
MyProject.exe MYSERVER DATABASE
```

In the first case I need to loop across all parameters using `ParamStr` and "decode" what they are. If they start with "-s:" I know that what follows is the server name. The second is more quick and dirty but may be more effective.

How to manage parameters that contain a "space"? Is it possible to automatically intercept them with ParamStr or should I handle all manually? (I mean is there a way to automatically tell to ParamStr that a parameter is containing a space (like using curly brackets or something).

What is the best practice?

Comment: You use double quotation marks to enclose a parameter containing spaces.

Comment: I don't know why I tried with all the combinations but not with double quotes!. Thanks. I noticed an interesting thing. If I write: "-s:Server name" and -s:"Server name" they are considered the same from ParamStr. This is very good, because writing "-s:Server Name" is not as user friendly as -s:"Server Name".

Comment: 1st approach is more handy and easy for you and end-users.. to "decode" params you can use `TStringList` (strip `-` symbols in the beginning of each line) and use its `Values`property with `NameValueSeparator` set to `:`

Comment: I believe that if an argument is required, then it should be "positional". If it's optional, then it should be "tagged".

Comment: @Nat Downside of position arguments is that they are hard for the human reader to parse. For sure it is clear to the computer but think of the poor human! Positional arguments also can make refactoring of a command line more challenging.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Should I go for a "position" approach or for some "tag" approach?

Without doubt you should tag your command line arguments. Positional approaches don't allow sufficient flexibility to omit parameters. Tagging makes it easier for the user to understand the arguments, especially when returning to previously written code. The tags should be self-documenting.

One common scenario when you would have untagged arguments is when you have a file name or a list of file names.

> How to manage parameters that contain a "space"?

The Windows convention is that spaces are escaped by putting double-quotes around the argument. The `ParamStr` parsing will recognise these and parse the arguments accordingly. What you see in `ParamStr(i)` is the argument with the quotes removed.

---

The RTL comes with a useful helper function to aid your command-line argument parsing: [`FindCmdLineSwitch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindCmdLineSwitch).

Comment: Thanks. See also my comment above.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the FindCmdLineSwitch. I always coded all that manually.

Comment: @user193655, IMO, `FindCmdLineSwitch` is your false friend. It brings the convenient sugar with simple switches, but makes fully fledged CLI a real headache. Consider: `prog -x -r src dest`. And your Q about "better" syntax makes little sense. Ask your power users instead, which CLI they are finding convenient.

Comment: I agree with that. To be able to handle such arguments, and this is the "common scenario" described in my answer, you really want the argument parser to eat switches/options and leave you with the remaining arguments.

Answer (score 12):

Delphi contains a really nice unit called CommandParser with a [TCommandParser](http://www.google.nl/search?q=delphi%20TCommandParser%20site:embarcadero.com) class that does commandline parsing for you.
Since it has [virtually no documentation](http://edn.embarcadero.com/print/40404#15UsingTCommandParser), here are a few things to get started.

I have a [HiddenExecutable example](http://bo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/71461) at our [open source bo repository](http://bo.codeplex.com).

Basically you:

- setup a `TComponent` that contains the properties you want to expose as commandline parameters (that is `THiddenExecuteSettings` in the [HiddenExecuteSettingsUnit](http://bo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71461#1510662)
- a commandline parser controller. In our case `THiddenExecuteArguments` in the [THiddenExecuteArgumentsUnit](http://bo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71461#1510664) (in retrospect not such a good name) that contains an `InitCommandLine` method that sets up a TCommandParser instance passing it your `TComponent`
- It then executes a couple of [AddSwitch](http://www.google.nl/search?q=delphi%20%22AddSwitch%22%20site:embarcadero.com) calls to setup the parameters with both abbreviated and full commandline switches (like `h` and `help`)
- You can then call the `ProcessCommandLine` method on the `TCommandParser` instance to process the commandline and fill the properties of your `TComponent` (in my example, this is done in the `ProcessCommandLine` method).

Now comes the fun:

- The `TCommandParser` has a `HelpText` method that fully automatically assembles a helptext based upon what you fed it with the `AddSwitch` methods.
- The `TCommandParser` also has a `SaveOptions` method that allows you to save the current settings of your TComponent into a settings file.

The Delphi units you need are these which you can get from the Embarcadero [radstudiodemos.sourceforge.net](http://radstudiodemos.sourceforge.net) demo repository:

```
CommandParser in '...\radstudiodemos.sourceforge.net\branches\RadStudio_XE2\Delphi\Database\dbExpress\Utils\CommandParser.pas',
PropertyHelpers in '...\radstudiodemos.sourceforge.net\branches\RadStudio_XE2\Delphi\Database\dbExpress\DbxDataPump\PropertyHelpers.pas',
ParseIds in '...\radstudiodemos.sourceforge.net\branches\RadStudio_XE2\Delphi\Database\dbExpress\DbxDataPump\ParseIds.pas',
```

**Edit:** [John Kaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74137/john-kaster) wrote a nice [article on EDN](http://edn.embarcadero.com/print/40404) that includes [more details on using the TCommandParser](http://edn.embarcadero.com/print/40404#15UsingTCommandParser).

Comment: Too bad I cannot find this unit anywhere in Delphi XE7 or its demos :(

Comment: @JerryDodge you are right; the last version it shipped in the examples was XE6. In XE7 they removed all the dbExpress demos, but it is still on-line at http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RadStudio_XE6/Object%20Pascal/Database/dbExpress/Utils/CommandParser.pas

Answer (score 7):

Your first question is merely a matter of taste. However, the second one I can answer. You use double quotation marks to enclose a parameter containing spaces. For example, if you have

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  i: integer;

begin
  for i := 0 to ParamCount do
    WriteLn(ParamStr(i));
  Readln;
end.
```

and start the application with arguments `one "two with spaces" three "four with spaces"`, then you get the output

```
C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\Project1.exe
one
two with spaces
three
four with spaces
```

Comment: Yes the interesting thing is that it works also nicely using: one two" with spaces" three four" with spaces"

Answer (score 1):

I'd separate Arguments (order based) and Options (switch based)
See "c:>help copy" for example.