# Is it possible to pass parameters from a batch file to delphi?

Tags: batch-file, delphi, parameters

I already know, that I can run an exe with parameters like so:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\Superuser\Documents
executable.exe -myparamater
```

But I can't figure out how I could recieve this parameter in delpi. My goal is to simply print the parameter. Does anybody have an idea how I could do this? I appreciate any help, sheers!

```
// Catch parameter here
WriteLn(parameter);
```

**Note:** My program is a simple console program made in delphi.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/9464603/576719

Comment: @LURD Ah cool, thank you very much. This is actually very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [`ParamCount`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamCount) and [`ParamStr`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr) functions:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  j: Integer;
begin

   for j := 1 to ParamCount do
     ShowMessage(ParamStr(j));

end;
```

Comment: [Official documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.ParamStr) which also links to an example

Comment: Also see [Command Line Support Routines](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Command_Line_Support_Routines)